# tesseract attribute error, how do I fix, need solution

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to train a ML model and need to use tesseract to convert image to text.
before,  I was getting the 'tesseract not found error"

but after doing some search here I found out I could add its path in front and that would solve the problem. But not I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'image_to_string'
```

How do I fix this?
this is the part of the code

```
        done = False
        res = pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'.image_to_string(done_cap)[:4]
        if res in done_strings:
            done = True
        
        return done, done_cap
```

I tried adding the path which solved the "tesseract not found" error but now I am getting attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

`image_to_string` is a function in pytesseract object  but not in str,
and here is a sample of how to use it:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
res = pytesseract.image_to_string(done_cap, lang='eng')[:4]
print(res)
```

follow-up:make sure your `done_cap` is an image obj,for example:

```
import cv2
done_cap=cv2.imread('./OCR.JPG')
code = pytesseract.image_to_string(done_cap, lang='eng')
print(code)
```

Comment: I tried using this just now, 
and now I am getting FileNotFound error and TesseractNotFoundError.

I have checked multiple times and the file is in the directory I specified above. 
I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: It just a template.you need make sure ```tesseract.exe```is in the path ```C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\``` and the ```done_cap``` is a image object